# Complicated C++ homework

Tags: c++

So I am working on a theater seating problem. The output of the program isn't lining up the way it should. I need help lining up the # and * with their proper columns. Also pressing Q to quit isn't working. Also, I need to figure out how to read the seating chart information from a file.If the file with the seating info does not exist yet, it means that all the seats are
empty. Whenever the program ends, the seating chart information should be stored in this file. Any other tips would also be helpful. Here is my code so far:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
# include <iostream>
# include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

void seats( double [] , int);
void mapSeats();
char movieMenu(char);

int main()
{
    const int rowNum = (15.0);
    double rowValue[rowNum]; //array to hold row pices
    char selection;
    int row2, col2;
    const char TAKEN = '#';//seats taken
    const char EMPTY = '*';//seats free
    const int row = 15;//number of rows
    const int col = 20;//number of col
    char map[row][col];//array to hold seat chart 



for(int i= 0;i<row;i++)//initiating array 
{
    for (int j=0;j<col;j++)
    {
        map[i][j]=EMPTY;
    }
}

mapSeats();

seats(rowValue, rowNum);//ask user to enter price of each row
cout << endl;

do
    {
        cout << "MOVIE THEATER MENU" << endl;
        cout << "------------------" << endl;
        cout << "1) Sell a ticket" << endl;
        cout << "Q) Quit program" << endl;
        cout << "Please make a selection: ";
        cin >> selection;

        if(selection =='1')
        {
            cout << "Please enter a row number and a seat number for the ticket: " ;
            cout << "Row # :" ;
            cin >> row2;
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Seat # :" ;
            cin >> col2;
            cout << endl;

            // Check if seat is free
        if(map[row2][col2] == TAKEN) {

            cout << "This seat is taken! Try another one. \n";
            continue; // start the loop again
                     }
            else // and if it is - sell the ticket
            map[row2][col2]=TAKEN;
        // Add the next loop to immediately see the effects:
            for (int i = 0; i < row; i++){
                for(int j = 0; j < col; j++){
                cout << map[i][j];
                }
cout << endl;
    }

        }
        else if(selection =='q'||selection=='Q')
        {
            cout << "Thank you for using the program." << endl;
        }
        else if(selection != '1' || selection !='q' || selection !='Q')
        {
            cout << "Invalid selection." << endl;
        }
    }while(selection != '1' || selection !='q' || selection !='Q');


system("pause");
return 0;
    }


    void seats(double rowPrice[], int row)
    {

cout << "Please enter a ticket price for each row." << endl;

for(int i = 0 ; i < row; i++)
{
    cout << "Row # " << i+1 << ": " ;
    cin >> rowPrice[i]; 
}
    }

    void mapSeats()
    {
    const char TAKEN = '#';//seats taken
    const char EMPTY = '*';//seats free
    const int rw=20;
    const int cl=15;

    cout << "Seats " ;
    for(int k = 0 ; k <20;k++) //loop to display nums 0 to 19
    {
    cout << fixed<< setw(2) << " " << k ;
    }

for(int i=0;i<rw;i++)//making array display what's in it
{
    cout << endl<< "Row " << i;
    for(int j=0;j<cl;j++)
    {
        cout << fixed<< setw(2) << "" << EMPTY;
    }
}
cout << endl;
    }
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a debugger or code generator.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. When asking a question, it's useful to provide the specific about what doesn't work, and how it doesn't work. Questions should ask about the attempt to fix the issue, as well as describing the problem in detail. For more information, see [ask]. Thank you!

Comment: Anyway, you might want to learn the basics of [debugging your code](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/a4-debugging-your-program-stepping-and-breakpoints).

Comment: Can I get help on how you might write this with the<ifstream> library?

Comment: you asked for a tip: clear names: `seats(rowValue, rowNum);//ask user to enter price of each row` shows that seats is not a clear name for the function.  So are most other names.  A name should show the intent of the variable/function/type/..., better too long than too cryptic

Answer (score 2):

Q to quit isn't working. Your logic is wrong

```
do
{
    ...
} while (selection !='q' && selection !='Q');
```

You carry on while the selection isn't 'q' **and** while the selection isn't 'Q'. Very common for newbies to get 'or' and 'and' mixed up.

Comment: +1 but "Your logic is wrong" then some code makes it sound like you're distilling the broken code rather than presenting the fixed code... :-)